# Is it possible to upload files to Snowflake via REST protocol directly?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anybody know whether it is possible to upload files to Snowflake using REST API endpoint directly, not using 3rd party drivers like https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dotnet-driver.html

I didn't find such information in their general API docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-apis.html But I assume that may be this information is not publically available. Does anybody know?

Comment: If you're referring to uploading files to stages, then no, you have to use a Snowflake connector.

Comment: The link you gave to the API docs explains exactly how to do this - what do you think is missing or what are you still confused by?

Answer (score 3):

The API you're referencing is for the Snowpipe REST API. This API is supported and publicly documented, but I don't think it's what you want.

The Snowpipe REST API does not upload files. Instead, you can invoke it to inform Snowpipe that there are new files in an external stage ready for copying into a table. Something else needs to get the files uploaded to the external stage in S3, Azure Blob, or GCP.

As far as a general-purpose REST API, it's supported only for Snowflake and partner developers use and not publicly documented. The best method is to use one of the drivers or connectors (ODBC, JDBC, .NET driver, etc.) to upload files. If that doesn't work for you, you can put the files to an external stage using whatever supported method you like for that cloud host. You can then use the Snowpipe REST API to initiate the copy into the table or just use SQL and a warehouse to do the copy into the table.